# Only the last value is being inserted in Coredata

Tags: ios, core-data

Im trying to add new values to an entity using blocks as follows,

```
[context performBlockAndWait:^{

                     // remove all rows
                     NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"PendingShipmentDetails"];
                     NSError *error;
                     NSArray * pendingShipments = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
                     for (NSManagedObject *pendingShipment in pendingShipments) {
                         [context deleteObject: pendingShipment];
                     }

                     // add new row(s)

                     NSManagedObject *pendingShipment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];

                     // TODO: set values here (e.g. [pendingShipment setValue:...)
                     [pendingShipment setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"shipmentno"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:proformaInvoiceNumber forKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:proformaInvoiceDate forKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:invoiceNo forKey:@"invoice_no"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:invoiceDate forKey:@"invoice_date"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:plannedShipmentDates forKey:@"planned_shipment_date"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:address forKey:@"point_of_contact"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:address forKey:@"empid"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:name forKey:@"products"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:qty forKey:@"quantity"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:rte forKey:@"rate"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:amt forKey:@"amount"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:img forKey:@"product_image"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:pendingStatus forKey:@"status"];

                     // save MOC
                     if ([context hasChanges]) {
                         (void)[context save:&error];
                     }
                 }];
```

First,I'm trying to remove all existing rows
Second, I'm populating it with new records.

The problem is that, only the last value is being inserted. How can I rectify it?

UPDATE:

```
-(void)pendingShipmentDetails
{
    keyChain = [[KeyChainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"LoginController" accessGroup:nil];
    NSString *username = [keyChain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrLabel)];

    NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"method\":\"pending_shipment_details\",\"data\":{\"username\":\"%@\"}}",username];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]];
    NSData *postData = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if ([data length] > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             [self receivedPendingShipmentDetailsData:data];
             NSString* pendingResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSData *jsonData = [pendingResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
             NSDictionary *valueDict = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"];

             NSArray *details = [valueDict objectForKey:@"details"];

             NSMutableArray* arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

             for (NSDictionary *response in details) {
                 NSString *invoiceNo = [response valueForKey:@"invoice_no"];
                 NSString *shipmentNumber = [response valueForKey:@"shipment_no"];
                 NSString *invoiceDate = [response valueForKey:@"invoice_date"];
                 NSString *proformaInvoiceNumber = [response valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
                 NSString *proformaInvoiceDate = [response valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
                 NSString *plannedShipmentDates = [response valueForKey:@"planned_shipment_dates"];
                 NSString *pointOfContact =[[response objectForKey:@"point_of_contact"] valueForKey:@"empid"];
                 NSString *pendingStatus = [response valueForKey:@"status"];
                 NSDictionary *productName = [response valueForKey:@"products"];
                 NSDictionary *quantity = [response valueForKey:@"quantity"];
                 NSDictionary *rate = [response valueForKey:@"rate"];
                 NSDictionary *amount = [response valueForKey:@"amount"];
                 NSDictionary *productImages = [response valueForKey:@"product_image"];
                 NSDictionary *point_of_contact = [response valueForKey:@"point_of_contact"];

                 NSString *qty;
                 NSString *rte;
                 NSString *img;
                 NSString *address;
                 NSString *name;
                 NSString *amt;

                 for (int i = 0; i < [productName count]; i++) {
                     //  NSLog(@"product name %@",[productName valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]]);
                     name = [productName valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]];
                 }

                 for (int i = 0; i < [quantity count]; i++) {
                     //  NSLog(@"quantity %@",[quantity valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]]);
                     qty = [quantity valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]];
                 }

                 for (int i = 0; i < [rate count]; i++) {
                     //  NSLog(@"rate %@",[rate valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]]);
                     rte = [rate valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]];
                 }

                 for (int i = 0; i < [amount count]; i++) {
                     // NSLog(@"amount %@",[amount valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]]);
                     amt = [amount valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]];
                 }


                 for (int i = 0; i < [productImages count]; i++) {
                     // NSLog(@"product image %@",[productImages valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]]);
                     img = [productImages valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]];
                 }

                 for (int i = 0; i < [point_of_contact count]; i++) {
                     //  NSLog(@"pt of ct %@",[point_of_contact valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"empid" ]]);
                     address = [point_of_contact valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"empid" ]];
                 }


                 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

                 // remove all rows
                 NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"PendingShipmentDetails"];
                 NSError *error;
                 NSArray * pendingShipments = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


                 [context performBlockAndWait:^{


                     // add new row(s)
                     NSLog(@"else block");
                     NSManagedObject *pendingShipment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                     NSError *error;

                     for (NSManagedObject *pendingShipment in pendingShipments) {
                         [context deleteObject: pendingShipment];

                     }
                     // TODO: set values here (e.g. [pendingShipment setValue:...)
                     [pendingShipment setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"shipmentno"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:proformaInvoiceNumber forKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:proformaInvoiceDate forKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:invoiceNo forKey:@"invoice_no"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:invoiceDate forKey:@"invoice_date"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:plannedShipmentDates forKey:@"planned_shipment_date"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:address forKey:@"point_of_contact"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:address forKey:@"empid"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:name forKey:@"products"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:qty forKey:@"quantity"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:rte forKey:@"rate"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:amt forKey:@"amount"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:img forKey:@"product_image"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:pendingStatus forKey:@"status"];

                     // save MOC
                     if ([context hasChanges]) {
                         (void)[context save:&error];
                     }
                 }];

             }
         }

         else if ([data length] == 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             [self emptyReply];
         }
         else if (connectionError != nil && connectionError.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut)
         {
             [self timedOut];
         }
         else if (connectionError != nil)
         {
             [self downloadError:connectionError];
         }
     }];

}
```

Comment: In `for-in` loop, you are deleting **all** the PendingShipmentDetails `Entities` each time you loop around and then you are adding new values. So in the last loop you will end up having only one Entity which does not get deleted.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I sort this issue out

Comment: Do you have any unique attribute i.e `NSDate`? On what criteria are you deleting your objects? You need to brief which object should be deleted or updated or inserted. OR on each fetch delete all earlier objects.

Comment: before adding new records, im deleting all existing records and add new records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to delete all the object from previous fetch on each new fetch of data. Then you should first delete all the persisted objects by calling `NSFetchRequest` for that Entity and after that add value using for-in loop as you are doing.

You can also use `NSBatchDeleteRequest`.

// some method or `IBAction` to refresh data
// first delete all the old ones.

```
-(void) deleteStoredData
{

     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
 [context performBlock:^{
                 // remove all rows
                 NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"PendingShipmentDetails"];
                 NSError *error;
                 NSArray * pendingShipments = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 for (NSManagedObject *pendingShipment in pendingShipments) {
     [context deleteObject: pendingShipment];
    }
}];

[self pendingShipmentDetails];
}
```

Now your pendingShipmentDetails will be same albeit deleting of objects.

```
-(void) pendingShipmentDetails{
// do saving using loop 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown doesn't loop through the new values - so there is only one value to be inserted.

If the code you have shown is called multiple times as you loop through the new data, then the first thing it does it delete everything - so either way, you will end up with only a single entry.

If you are implementing the second approach, you need to split out the deletion block, and do that once, before you step through the new data.

Comment: can you please elobrate with reference to my code? thank you

Comment: In your code above - the section `remove all rows` is executed every time `performBlockAndWait` is called, but the section `add new row(s)` is only called once.  Could you add the code where you call this block?

Comment: that block is within a method already. hence if that method is being invoked, automatically, the block will also be executed. I will post the entire method

Comment: there are a few odd things.  You define arrayList, but never use it.  You define qty, name, etc., and step through a list of responses for each, but overwrite the answer each time rather than loading into an array.  The block to delete rows is repeated every time you go through the main loop, rather than being executed once, when you confirm that data has been returned

Comment: can you please help me to sort out that?